# I would like join two csv files

Tags: text-processing, csv, join

I would like join two `csv` files:

file1:

```
19/02/2016 22:00;16.70
19/02/2016 22:30;16.80
19/02/2016 23:00;16.80
19/02/2016 23:30;16.70
```

file2:

```
19/02/2016 22:00;39.50
19/02/2016 22:30;41.00
19/02/2016 23:00;40.30
19/02/2016 23:30;40.40
```

Expected result:

```
19/02/2016 22:00;16.70;39.50
19/02/2016 22:30;16.80;41.00
19/02/2016 23:00;16.80;40.30
19/02/2016 23:30;16.70;40.40
```

Comment: do all lines match or could there be one entry missing in one of the files?

Comment: Usually the `join` command should do the trick, but your needs are not 100% clear. Maybe you can work it out on your own with `man join`?

Answer (score 5):

Uh, self answering question

```
join -t ';' file1 file2
```

```
19/02/2016 22:00;16.70;39.50
19/02/2016 22:30;16.80;41.00
19/02/2016 23:00;16.80;40.30
19/02/2016 23:30;16.70;40.40
```

Answer (score 0):

```
paste file1 file2 | while IFS="$(printf '\t')" read -r f1 f2; do echo $f1";"$(echo $f2|cut -d";" -f2) ;done
```

This produces the output from your files as desired. Suitability to other formats, may require additional work, such as missing lines, unsorted files, etc.